# MySQL to MSSQL via linked server: blob to varbinary

Tags: mysql, sql-server, blob, linked-server, varbinary

I have a mysql database that I need to be imported into sql server via a linked server. Two of the mysql columns are blob and mediumblob. The columns in mssql are varbinary(max). When I execute a query at the linked server, I get the error:

OLE DB provider "STREAM" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 19
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

The error goes away when I exclude the blob and medium blob columns from the select statement. Is there a conversion or workaround for this?